# I need xml design guideline

Tags: xml, android-layout, design-patterns, android-studio-3.0

The required design is a scrollable screen with 3 to 4 almost similar blocks:

[image: its a scrollable screen with 3 to 4 almost similar blocks]

This is what I've been trying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.santalu.diagonalimageview.DiagonalImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/demo"
            app:di_borderColor="#FF5722"
            app:di_borderEnabled="false"
            app:di_direction="left"
            app:di_overlap="60dp"
            app:di_position="bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Maternity care plan"
            android:textColor="#040303"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:text="Maternity care plan"
            android:textColor="#050505"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <com.example.diagnalimageview.DividerView
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layerType="software"
            custom:color="#050505"
            custom:dashGap="2dp"
            custom:dashLength="5dp"
            custom:dashThickness="1dp"
            custom:orientation="vertical" />

       
        <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/pregnancy_plane_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/line1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_progress_container"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:translationZ="90dp"

                custom:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                custom:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                custom:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <com.timqi.sectorprogressview.ColorfulRingProgressView
                    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    app:bgColor="#e1e1e1"
                    app:fgColorEnd="#5900FF"
                    app:fgColorStart="#5900FF"
                    app:percent="0"
                    app:startAngle="0"
                    app:strokeWidth="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0%"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--determine center to circular shape-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dummy view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/circle_progress_container"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/circle_progress_container"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circle_progress_container"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/circle_progress_container"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />



            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/pregnancy_plane"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:cardElevation="12dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:translationY="-20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummy_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                card_view:contentPadding="1dp">


    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="PLAN YOUT PREGNANCY\nTHE WAY YOU WANT"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="32dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:text="PLANNING MY PREGNANCY"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
              
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>





        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.example.diagnalimageview.DividerView
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pregnancy_plane_container"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:translationY="-36dp"
            android:layerType="software"
            custom:color="#050505"
            custom:dashGap="2dp"
            custom:dashLength="5dp"
            custom:dashThickness="1dp"
            custom:orientation="vertical" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/line2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_progress_container2"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:translationZ="90dp"

                custom:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                custom:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                custom:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.timqi.sectorprogressview.ColorfulRingProgressView
                    android:id="@+id/pregnancy_choices_progress"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:bgColor="#e1e1e1"
                    app:fgColorEnd="#5900FF"
                    app:fgColorStart="#5900FF"
                    app:percent="0"
                    app:startAngle="0"
                    app:strokeWidth="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="0%" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <!--determine center to circular shape-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dummy view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/circle_progress_container2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/circle_progress_container2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/circle_progress_container2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/circle_progress_container2"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/pregnancy_choices"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:translationY="-20dp"
                app:cardElevation="12dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummy_view2"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                card_view:contentPadding="1dp">


                <!--<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dummy_view">-->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="PLAN YOUT PREGNANCY\nTHE WAY YOU WANT"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="32dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:text="PLANNING MY PREGNANCY"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <!-- </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>-->
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now the problems is for blocks view hierarchy is

```
ConstraintLayout
     RelativeLayout.            -for progress chart
     Button(dummyview)          -to determine center of progress chart
     cardview                   -to give elevated look I used compact padding 12dp
```

That padding make bottom space between constraint layout and cardview. So when I tried to draw vertical line between first block and second block. line top was 12dp down from the block than I used translationY= -12dp to fix it but now vertical line is touching second block.

My output:
[image: myoutput]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to fix the issue by replacing cardview with LinearLayout and used drawable shadow for LinearLayout to make it look like cardview,